# Ethics and animal welfare posts deleted

Tags: support

Several posts about animal welfare of mine have been deleted on this site. However, my posts seemed to add much substance and color to this site. So, why have they been deleted?

Answer (score 2):

We do appreciate your enthusiasm, it just needs to be focussed a little more to the kind of questions that work here.

The [system deleted them](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) via a process called Roomba.

In your case they were asked more than 9 days ago, had a zero score and no answers.

If a post is closed and you don't edit it to address the reason for closure then that's what happens I'm afraid. If you do edit any of your deleted questions then just flag them for moderator attention so we can consider undeleting and reopening them for you. You'll need to properly address the reason why the question was closed though.

A significant number of your questions ask for opinions and those really don't do well here. We have a specific close reason for opinion based questions. Nor to polling questions, i.e. asking us all what we think, work well. Try to stick to questions that are more factual.

If you want to find your deleted questions you can use [this  link](/users/deleted-questions/current) (which will load the pages for the currently logged-in user).